# Unable to acess media after making folder static express

Tags: node.js, express

I have an image in folder but cann't display on website

**server.js**

```
express.static('public')    
app.use(express.static("public", { 'index': ['login.html', 'index.htm'] }));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Project folder

```
- core 
- lib
- node_modules
- public
    ---> css
    ---> js
    ---> img
  index.html
- route
```

Comment: how are you trying to access it

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski in html I use '<img src="img/pic1jpg" class="card-img-top" id="pic">'

Comment: `"img/pic1jpg"` isn't there a `.` missing there?

Comment: @GuyIncognito Oh, I accidentally deleted it before commenting. But my code is correct